# htaccess eliminate folders

Tags: php, .htaccess

This is my htaccess code,

It re-write urls from this

```
mysite.com/profile.php?id=123&network=stackoverflow
```

to this

```
mysite.com/stackoverflow/profile.php?id=123
```

but the problem is, users cannot reach js,css or images. 
i.e.

```
mysite.com/css/style.css
mysite.com/js/javascript.js
mysite.com/img/logo.png
```

How can I eliminate real folders like img,js,css etc..?

My htaccess is,

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/(.*)$ /$2?network=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following will ignore requests to actual files/directories

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\/]+)/(.*)$ /$2?network=$1 [QSA,L]
```